Hypothesis testing categorical variables: Should we include them in logistic regression models?
I have observational data with binary treatment/control where users are exposed to a new program and covariates like the below:

Race of the user (about 5 races)
Continent of origin of the user (3 origins)

My outcome is a binary conversion variable. So I set my regression model to include all main effects and all two-way interactions..
However, I'm not clear on if this is the right thing to do because it creates the reference category.
So I'm wondering:

Should I just conduct chi-square tests for each cohort group against the null hypothesis of the cohort control effect?


Presumably you are interested in something like "Does the new UI element work for everyone (irrespective of device or race)?". I assume your model is something like conversion ~ new_element + race + device + new_element:race + new_element:device + race:device + new_element:race:device (if you think both rare or device could affect the effect of the new UI element) or maybe conversion ~ new_element + race + device + new_element:device + race:device (if you don't think that race could effect the effect of the new UI element)? In such a case the new_element term only tells you something for the reference category for all factor levels.
Ignoring whether all subgroups are properly powered (which may be a problem if there's not that many records for some of the rarer combinations), you could from the logistic regression test the null hypothesis that the proportions are the same and do this for every device + race combinations (if you have interactions for  new_element with both in your model, otherwise just for the device categories). This ends up being 15 tests (or 3 if you only have new UI element by device interaction). Various packages can help you setting up these contrasts (e.g. the emmeans package, if you use R).
There's lots of alternatives, like having a fixed new_element main effect, but letting the interactions with each sub-category combination be random effects. One could then test whether the main effect is significant and look at/test whether the across category variation is "small enough" (whatever that means in your context, e.g. small enough that the difference in the log-odds of conversion are practically irrelevant).

It's true that the coefficients from the summary of a model fit are relative to a reference category & in case of interactions not particularly interpretable. More or less any software should have features for getting you comparisons such as conditional (on the categories) average treatment effects. E.g. if you use R the emmeans package has the emmeans and contrast statements. These would usually also enable any custom contrast you want to specify (that's usually a bit trickier), which again in R emmeans would do for you (even if you want things like differences in proportions or ratios).
